# Using xpath / html to read and find certain aspects from a html file

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, xquery

Edit: here is the code I have so far:

```
for $x in doc("http://www.domain.com")/body/div
return if ($x/@id="content")
then <h1>{data($x/div[3]/span)}</h1>
else <h1> Nothing </h1>
```

So I basically want it to return the value and have it appear on my website:  value

Basically what I would like to do is make is so that on my website I can find different values from another website and display them on the website. For example I want it to look through a html document (all the code, not just text on the webpage) and find a certain part of it e.g. Get value by finding

in the webpage and getting value from it.

```
<div><p>Value </p></div>
```

I have been able to make it find the code area where the value is stored as above but not automatically record the value.

Sorry if hard to understand

Comment: You can use [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to find specific elements in HTML document.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really difficult for us to help debug a verbal description of your code. How about you edit your question and add the code that you have - so we can help you figure out how to make it work the way you want it to. Don't put code in the comments, because formatting is dreadful - please put it in your question by clicking "edit". cheers.

Comment: Also, is this a cross domain request?

Comment: If `domain.com` is not the same domain that makes the request, I suggest you look at YQL